# AWS FARGATE ECS - Exact steps to deploy new Docker images with aws CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, aws-cli, fargate

We run services in AWS FARGATE... our Docker builds are tagged before we push them to AWS with a `Makefile`.

I committed changes to a Docker service, ran `make`, and I see the new Docker image tag when I run `aws ecr --profile staging --region us-east-1  describe-images --repository-name "bind"`:

```
{
    "registryId": "8675309",
    "repositoryName": "bind",
    "imageDigest": "sha256:0d3f8d5341286a8e8eb4ddfff2865638b35f8ff83823f8c2cee4bad359d0ffff",
    "imageTags": [
        "0.0.3-0.20210825120405-81e9cffff200"
    ],
    "imageSizeInBytes": 105228639,
    "imagePushedAt": "2021-08-25T12:05:02-05:00",
    "imageManifestMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
    "artifactMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json"
},
```

I am rather new to FARGATE, and I can't figure out the `aws` CLI to replace the current (outdated) Docker image.  Which commands should I run?  I'm open to using `aws` CLI or `boto`.

Answer (score 1):

The image versions are defined in task definition, so you'll have to create a new task definition (or update the existing one) changing the Docker image tag.

See [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-task-definition.html) for a task definition template.